# Java Web Start Error "Can not find message file"

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have have two versions for the `javaws.exe` one under `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` & the other under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin`. but when I click on the `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe` I got the following error "**Can not find message file**".

So what might be the problem?  Baring in mind that I am unable to run any of the applications that need Java Web Start to run.

Comment: Where does your JAVA_HOME point to ? and is %JAVA_HOME%/bin added to your PATH variable ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Java_Home points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06. and i do not have JAVA_HOME in the PATH.

Comment: i added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the path but the problem is still there. the full path looks as follow :- %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Did you check this ? https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10081153

Comment: i check it,,, if i understand the topic well but i am not using \ at the end of any path

Comment: I would say, uninstall Java, restart your machine and reinstall Java (so that all the registry entries are set properly)

Comment: this what i was trying to avoid ...

Comment: Even if you were trying to avoid it, reinstalling java is your best option, and it may also fix your other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301643/windows-can-not-find-bin-ssvagent-exe

Comment: re-installing java has solved the problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

re-installing java has solved the problem...

Answer (score 4):

You are likely to be missing the following values (example):

```
----8<----
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Web Start]
"CurrentVersion"="1.7.0_06"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Web Start\1.7.0_06]
"Home"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin"
----8<----
```

Maybe you need separate values for both of the two runtimes, but likely you want to use WS only with the JRE installation.

I hope this helps anyone else expiriencing this message.

Comment: This was much quicker than a reinstall.  In my case, the value for "Home" was pointing to an invalid location.