# Windows can not find '\bin\ssvagent.exe'

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have type the following on my windows 7 CMD:_

```
javaws -viewer
```

But the following error was raised:- "Windows can not find '\bin\ssvagent.exe' ", so what is going wrong?

Comment: that file is generally located in `.../jre/bin` - if you call javaws from that folder it should work fine. Alternatively, you can access the cache viewer from the Java Control Panel (General tab > View).

Comment: i click directly on the C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe file but i got the following error "Can not find message file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy ways to run your command properly:

1) For a permanent fix you need to add the java bin folder you your windows calsspath.
Then when you use the javaws command it will know where the ssvagent.exe file is located.

2) If you only need to use this once or twice then you will need to naviagte to the **jre** bin folder, using: `cd "[path to`**`jre`**`bin folder]"`
example: `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"`

Once you have done that, you can use your command: `javaws -viewer`

---

More info about adding java to your classpath:

- http://www.ehow.com/how_7166816_set-up-java-classpath-windows.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

---

If for some reason the above options don't help, then you need to reinstall java